# What are the units of $\Bbb R[X]/(X^2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> What are the units of $\Bbb R[X]/(X^2)$?

It is clear that the elements of $\Bbb R[X]/(X^2)$ is of the form $aX+b$ mod $X^2$ where $a,b \in \Bbb R$. I have observed that if $b=0$ then $aX+b$ is a divisor of zero and consequently it is not a unit. But if $a=0$ then for all $b \ne 0$ we have $aX+b$ is a unit. So we are now left with the case where neither $a$ nor $b$ is zero. In this case if $aX+b$ is a unit of the above quotient ring then $\exists\ cX+d$ with $c,d \in \Bbb R$ such that $(aX+b)(cX+d) +(X^2) = 1 + (X^2)$. Which is possible if $ad+bc=0$ and $bd=1$.But at this stage I got stuck. How can I proceed from here to reach at the desired stage.

Please help me in this regard.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** $:$ I have found $c = - \frac {a} {b^2}$ and $d = \frac {1} {b}$ since $b \ne 0$. So the set of units are $(\Bbb R[X] / (X^2)) \setminus (X)$. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you know about local rings, your ring is local, with unique maximal ideal $\bar{X}$ and from the theory of local rings, every element not contained in the ideal is a unit.

Comment: I expect it would be more common to write $a+bX$ in this setting. Since $X^2=0$, intuitively we think of $X$ as a small quantity, so this is like the first part of a Taylor expansion, which goes $a+bX+cX^2+\cdots$.

Comment: The accepted answer works things out explicitly, but what you've already done is enough. As you've observed, it is necessary that $b$ be a unit, but this is in fact sufficient. Since $aX$ is nilpotent in $\mathbb{R}[X]/\langle X^{2} \rangle$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then if $b \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$, then $b+aX$ is the sum of a unit and a nilpotent element, which is always again a unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $aX+b\in \Bbb{R}[X]/(X^2)$. One has if $b\neq 0$

$$(aX+b)\left(-{a\over b^2}X+{1\over b}\right)=1$$

So any element $aX+b$ of $\Bbb{R}[X]/(X^2)$ with $b\neq 0$ is a unit

Comment: I have already found it myself. Can I still accept this answer knowing all the things?

Comment: I was typing when you found it. I was editing to add the local ring stuff. But my typing is slow.